# Verify Geodatabase Integrity?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, data-backup

I'm regularly backing up an ArcSDE Geodatabase. The backup is done by using arcpy.Copy_management to copy datasets from SDE to a local File GeoDatabase.

How can I verify the integrity of the back up and ensure that nothing is corrupt?

Comment: You mean, besides creating a new database instance, installing the backup in it, and testing whether you have full functionality?

Comment: please edit the question with more information about the DB, backup type db or external, OS, gdb version.

Comment: When I was faced with the same problem on PostGis I did exactly what @Vince said, but being free-to-install on a different computer (the PostgreSQL/PostGIS part) I was able to do that to verify its integrity. I was looking to prove that the backup process created a viable file that *could* be used to rebuild SDE should the servers' RAID fail or the database become corrupt; also I created a test DB, put data into it, backed it up, removed features then restored. Not all backup options create a viable file.. ultimately any answer *has* to be database specific as thats where the backup is done.

Answer (score 1):

This answer relates to *File*Geodatabases, as asked.  Yes, I know that there are [many enterprise geodatabase tools](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-geodatabase-administration-toolset.htm), but these only apply to RDBMS network connections.  None of these apply to the question of how to verify the integrity of a file GDB.

We do a very similar backup (as well as database and critical feature class backups) but yes, there appears to be no real 'Check GDB' tool by Esri.  Of course, an unverified backup is almost as useful as no backup...

If you have the time, you can [export to XML](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/exporting-a-geodatabase-schema-to-an-xml-workspace-document.htm) which will parse the entire geodatabase, but that is a very long process.  I just did it taking almost 2 hours for a 1.5GB GDB holding ~300 objects.

I think one efficient solution might be to use a Python script or Modelbuilder to [rebuild all spatial indexes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/modifying-a-spatial-index.htm) in the backup FGDB, or check the length of all non-spatial objects which should check each object and detect any corruption.  If you have access to Safe Software FME, it would not be hard to extract sample extents iterating through each object to perform much the same task.  The way the GDB container works, as soon as you access the object an error will be thrown if it's bad.

In practice, a quick check that is easy to do is to run a [Recover FGDB](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/recover-file-geodatabase.htm) on the backup to a temporary FGDB.  Note that "...tool can only recover simple feature classes and tables. Complex data and relationships will not be recovered."  Feature datasets, topologies, relationship classes, and maybe feature-linked annotation won't make it across so you can't simply compare container counts.  On the same FGDB for me, this tool took less than two minutes which I think is a reasonable 'verification' of the container contents.

I also do a quick scan in Catalog and preview either geometry or table for random items - if the FGDB is corrupt this will fail, but of course this is neither a comprehensive or replicable test.